# Why argv is allways (NULL) in my execve system call monitor

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I wrote lkm hook that monitor the execve system call  it basically should print the parameter of the char ** argv .
and i tried to print the argv but it didn't worked i must say that the filename parameter and the env variable  were printed fine but when i print the argv the result is

```
(NULL)
```

when i run the ls -all command or any other program
this is my code

```
char argv[100];
char *mid[4];


asmlinkage long our_execl(struct pt_regs *tr)
{

copy_from_user(mid,tr->cx,4);
strncpy_from_user(argv,mid[1], 253);
printk("%s\n",argv);

}
```

Comment: If you really want help you should post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @pifor I think it quit minimal doesn't it?

Comment: Actually it's too minimal and it's not reproducible at all: you should give minimal code that can be compiled and run to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @pifor do you have a suggest for to make it more minimally

Comment: @DanielHaish: problem is not that it s *not enough* minimal but that it is *too* minimal.

Comment: i think that (NULL) is the value and not an empty string otherwise you would see nothing

Comment: @pifor is it batter now? what information is missing ?

Comment: The variables in your example code do not make sense.

Comment: @IanAbbott sorry i copied it wrong is it now?

Comment: Have you tried copying mid[0] instead of mid[1]? Perhaps the program doesn't have any arguments except for the program name?

Comment: @user253751 I tried i am not getting (NULL) just empty log instead

Comment: @amal6h It's slightly better, but what is `mid` pointing to?

Comment: The code you provide is really too careless. What's `mid` pointing to? Does it really have space for 100 bytes? Do you have an understanding of how many pointers is that (`argv` parameter of `execve()` is an array of pointers)? Why the first pointer you access is at index 1? Why do you attempt to copy 253 bytes to `argv[]` array when it only has space for 100 bytes?

Why do you think that `argv` of `execve()` is at `tr->cx`? Are you on 64-bit Linux?

Please make it the minimal code for a kernel module that cleanly does what you want. It won't be large. Then people will be able to help.

Comment: @Aleksey I went to get the first parameter that the command get so i need index 1 i don't know the long of the string and it bad the malloc in kernel so i used 256 . and yes argv is pointer of pointers (char *__user* argv) I edit i copied the mid variable wrong